# Parse Campaign Monitor's HTTP POST request in JSON using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webhooks, campaign-monitor

Basically I am working with Campaign Monitor's webhook. I have created an update webhook so when email is updated, Campaign Monitor sends HTTP POST request to the URL I specified. I am having trouble parsing JSON.

Here it is:

```
POST /subscribe HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:80
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "Events": [
        {
            "CustomFields": [
                {
                    "Key": "website", 
                    "Value": "http:\/\/example.org"
                }
            ],
           "Date": "2010-12-14 11:32:00",
           "OldEmailAddress": "test@example.org",
           "EmailAddress": "test@example.org",
           "Name": "Test Subscriber Renamed",
           "Type": "Update",
           "State": "Active"
        }
    ],
    "ListID": "96c0bbdaa54760c8d9e62a2b7ffa2e13"
}
```

I looked at the example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc197957(v=vs.95).aspx but couldn't get to work it out.

I would like to get OldEmailAddress, EmailAddress, Type and State. Thanks,

Reference to Campaign Monitor's webhooks https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/webhooks/#currently_available_webhooks

Thanks,

Comment: Are you facing any error or exception while parsing json or do you need approach to parse it?

Comment: I need an approach to parse it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you try to get json data from url using C#. First of all you need to get NuGet packages called Newtonsoft.Json

Then you can use this code

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{

  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yourapisite.com"); // Not whole link, just host

  var url = "link after your host url";

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
     var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     YourClass responsedata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(data.Result.ToString());



  }
```

}

Hope this help.

**EDIT**
First of all,Newtonsoft is a very sensitive about deserialize json.Every json property like CustomField has a property with same name. I edited my answer to your code. Please check and let me know how is working.

I cannot debug this code because I didnt know your api url.

```
public class Events {
    public Events()
    {
        this.eventData = new List<EventData>();
    }
    public string ListID { get; set; } 
    public List<EventData> eventData { get; set; } 
}
public class EventData {
    public EventData()
    {
        this.CustomFields = new List<CustomFields>();
    }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string OldEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public List<CustomFields> CustomFields { get; set; }

}
public class CustomFields
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fatih. I can now get the json string but having trouble parsing it. I guess my class structure is not right. Here is my code: Events events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(json); public class Events
    {
        public string ListID { get; set; }
        public EventData eventData { get; set; }
    }
    public class EventData
    {
        public string date { get; set; } // and more elements for event
    } // I can get the ListID but not Event data